# mysql CREATE USER

Tags: mysql, database

I am logged into mysql...

```
mysql -u root -pmypass
```

And I have run the following command to remove the database user which worked succesfully

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES; DROP USER 'myuser_shop';
```

I can then add user successfully using the following command, again this works successfully

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES; CREATE USER 'myuser_shop' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

The above command create a user with the host as a wildcard (%) The issue I am having is if I was to create a user with the host being say localhost or an external IP i get the following error:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES; DROP USER 'myuser_shop';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES; CREATE USER 'myuser_shop'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'myuser_shop'@'localhost'
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you are trying looks ok to me. Have you checked out http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28331 to see if your problem is described there?

Comment: +1 for your comment for Svetlozar Angelov - it solved my problem as well!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug reported here - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28331

See if your user exists after you drop it.

Comment: I have checked the 'user' table in the 'mysql' database and there is no reference to myuser_shop.

Comment: Actually although it didn't appear in the user table, it must have existed in the db file, i specifically removed the FLUSH PRIVILEGES; DROP USER 'myuser_shop'@'localhost'; and the CREATE USER then worked! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check following 2 tables if user is still there after DROP USER command:
mysql.user and mysql.db.

Delete user from both, then run FLUSH PRIVILEGES and then you can recreate the user.

Answer (score 0):

drop user 'username@localhost
'

Comment: You should explain your answer more

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you to use phpmyadmin its very esey do do with that.

steps:

1. open phpmyadmin
2. go to admin section
3. hit on add user account
4. put user name and password
5. set privileges

that's all 
see in action on youtube [ [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zofdrNiFJ_g)  ]

Answer (score -1):

You have to manualy remove records with from mysql.tables_priv also.

Comment: Manually messing about in the `mysql.*` is highly not-recommended.